# How to Compare Two Columns in Excel in the Same Sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

I made this macro to highlight the same values in the same worksheet but I would like it to go one by one not highlight all numbers at once.

```
Sub series()
    'Definición de variables
    Dim rango As String
    Dim valor As String
    Dim resultado As Range
    Dim primerResultado As String
    Dim cont As Integer
    'Solicitar información al usuario
    rango = "A1:XFD1048576"
    valor = InputBox("Ingresa el VALOR a buscar:")
    If valor = "" Then Exit Sub
    'Inicializar contador de coincidencias
    cont = 0   'Primera búsqueda del valor dentro del rango
    Set resultado = Range(rango).Find(What:=valor, _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False, _
                    SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not resultado Is Nothing Then    'Si el resultado de la búsqueda no es vacío
        primerResultado = resultado.Address
        Do                              'Inicia bucle para hacer varias búsquedas
            cont = cont + 1
            resultado.Interior.ColorIndex = 4    'Cambia el color de fondo de la celda
            Set resultado = Range(rango).FindNext(resultado) 'Vuelve a buscar el valor
        Loop While Not resultado Is Nothing And resultado.Address <> primerResultado
    Else
        cont = 0
        MsgBox "Se encontraron " & cont & " coincidencias."
        'valor = InputBox("Ingresa el VALOR a buscar:")
    End If
    Application.Run ("series")
    'valor = InputBox("Ingresa el VALOR a buscar:")
    'Muestra un cuadro de diálogo con el número de coincidencias
    'MsgBox "Se encontraron " & cont & " coincidencias."
End Sub
```

Comment: My suggestion, is to set 2 arrays to the two columns you want to compare then run a loop through them comparing. It will be faster than what you have and a lot easier to understand.

Comment: I reformatted your posted code - let me know if I should change anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will ask confirmation from the user to highlight each cell found (untested)

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub series()
    'Definición de variables (Definition of variables)
    Dim rango As String, valor As String, resultado As Range
    Dim primerResultado As String, cont As Integer

    'Solicitar información al usuario (Get information from the user)
    rango = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    valor = InputBox("Ingresa el VALOR a buscar:")
    If valor = "" Then Exit Sub

    cont = 0    'Inicializar contador de coincidencias (Initialize Find)

    'Primera búsqueda del valor dentro del rango (First search for value in the range)
    Set resultado = Range(rango).Find(What:=valor, _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False, _
                    SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not resultado Is Nothing Then    'Si el resultado de la búsqueda no es vacío
        primerResultado = resultado.Address
        Do                              'Inicia bucle para hacer varias búsquedas
            If MsgBox("Resaltar celular?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
                cont = cont + 1
                resultado.Interior.ColorIndex = 4    'Cambia el color de fondo de la celda
            End If
            Set resultado = Range(rango).FindNext(resultado) 'Vuelve a buscar el valor
        Loop While Not resultado Is Nothing And resultado.Address <> primerResultado
    Else
        MsgBox "Se encontraron " & cont & " coincidencias."
    End If
End Sub
```